# Java - Bank System + Transaction Function

Tags: java

I am trying to create a bank system (object oriented) that can hold/store account information which the user will have to input. When the account has been created, it can be located/found using the account number for withdrawing, depositing, viewing transactions and deleting.

The problem that I have come across is the transaction section. For each account, you must be able to store only the last 6 tranactions in ascending order and this must be printed. Can you please guide me on what points I should be looking for.

```
class BankAccount{

private int accountNumber;
private String holderName;
private String holderAddress;
private String openDate;
private double balance;
private double[] transactions;
private String[] transactionsSummary;
private int numOfTransactions;
private  static int noOfAccounts=0;

public String getAccountInfo(){
    return "Account number: " + accountNumber + "\nCustomer Name: " + holderName + "\nHolder's Address: " + holderAddress + "\nOpen Date: " + openDate +  "\nBalance:" + balance +"\n";
}

public String getTransactionInfo(int n)
{
    String transaction = transactionsSummary[n];
    if (transaction == null) {
        return "No transaction exists with that number.";
    }
    else {
        return transaction;
    }
}

public BankAccount(String abc, double xyz, String address, String open){
    holderName = abc;
    balance = xyz;
    holderAddress = address;
    openDate = open;
    noOfAccounts ++;
    accountNumber = noOfAccounts;
    transactions = new double[100];
    transactionsSummary = new String[100];
    transactions[0] = balance;
    transactionsSummary[0] = "A balance of : $" + Double.toString(balance) + " was deposited.";
    numOfTransactions = 1;
}

public int getAccountNum(){
    return accountNumber;
}

public int getNumberOfTransactions() {
    return numOfTransactions;
}

public void deposit(double amount){

    if (amount<=0) {
        System.out.println("Amount to be deposited should be positive");
    } else {
        balance = balance + amount;
        transactions[numOfTransactions] = amount;
        transactionsSummary[numOfTransactions] = "$" + Double.toString(amount) + " was deposited.";
        numOfTransactions++;
    }
}

public void withdraw(double amount)
{
    if (amount<=0){
        System.out.println("Amount to be withdrawn should be positive");
    }
    else
    {
        if (balance < amount) {
            System.out.println("Insufficient balance");
        } else {
            balance = balance - amount;
            transactions[numOfTransactions] = amount;
            transactionsSummary[numOfTransactions] = "$" + Double.toString(amount) + " was withdrawn.";
            numOfTransactions++;
        }
    }
}

}//end of class




class BankAccount{

private int accountNumber;
private String holderName;
private String holderAddress;
private String openDate;
private double balance;
private double[] transactions;
private String[] transactionsSummary;
private int numOfTransactions;
private  static int noOfAccounts=0;

public String getAccountInfo(){
    return "Account number: " + accountNumber + "\nCustomer Name: " + holderName + "\nHolder's Address: " + holderAddress + "\nOpen Date: " + openDate +  "\nBalance:" + balance +"\n";
}

public String getTransactionInfo(int n)
{
    String transaction = transactionsSummary[n];
    if (transaction == null) {
        return "No transaction exists with that number.";
    }
    else {
        return transaction;
    }
}

public BankAccount(String abc, double xyz, String address, String open){
    holderName = abc;
    balance = xyz;
    holderAddress = address;
    openDate = open;
    noOfAccounts ++;
    accountNumber = noOfAccounts;
    transactions = new double[100];
    transactionsSummary = new String[100];
    transactions[0] = balance;
    transactionsSummary[0] = "A balance of : $" + Double.toString(balance) + " was deposited.";
    numOfTransactions = 1;
}

public int getAccountNum(){
    return accountNumber;
}

public int getNumberOfTransactions() {
    return numOfTransactions;
}

public void deposit(double amount){

    if (amount<=0) {
        System.out.println("Amount to be deposited should be positive");
    } else {
        balance = balance + amount;
        transactions[numOfTransactions] = amount;
        transactionsSummary[numOfTransactions] = "$" + Double.toString(amount) + " was deposited.";
        numOfTransactions++;
    }
}

public void withdraw(double amount)
{
    if (amount<=0){
        System.out.println("Amount to be withdrawn should be positive");
    }
    else
    {
        if (balance < amount) {
            System.out.println("Insufficient balance");
        } else {
            balance = balance - amount;
            transactions[numOfTransactions] = amount;
            transactionsSummary[numOfTransactions] = "$" + Double.toString(amount) + " was withdrawn.";
            numOfTransactions++;
        }
    }
}

}//end of class
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks so much for the help. How should I proceed? Do i need to completely remove array for both accounts and transaction? Where do I implement Map and linked list?

Answer (score 3):

I'll only give you some hints.

First of all, Java is an OO language, and you should thus use objects. Instead of having two arrays to hold the transaction amounts and the transaction summaries, you should have a single array holding objects of type `Transaction`. The `Transaction` class should have a field `amount` and a field `summary`.

Second: instead of using an array, you could use a `List<Transaction>`. Every time a new Transaction comes in, you add it at the end of the list. If the list size becomes bigger than 6, you remove the first element of the list (the oldest one). A LinkedList is a good choice for this functionality. Since the list has a size, you don't need to maintain a `numOfTransactions` by yourself. The list does that for you.

You're using a String to hold a date. That is not the appropriate type. You should use a Date.

And you're using a static field to hold the number of created accounts. That is bad design. You should instead have a Bank object, containing all the accounts of a bank (as a `Map<Integer, BankAccount>` for example, which would allow to find an account based on its number).

Comment: Hi. Thanks so much for the help. Do I need to remove the array completely for the project and replace it with list? How would I store accounts and transaction so that it's linked?

Comment: The class BankAccount should have a field `latestTransactions`, of type `List<Transaction>`. The class Bank should have a field `accounts` of type `Map<Integer, BankAccount>`. You don't implement Map and LinkedList. Those are classes that are provided by the JDK.

Comment: How can I add the account in Bank to the Map<Integer, BankAccount>?

Comment: `accounts.put(account.getNumber(), account)` Have you read the javadoc of Map? If not, then do it. That's how you learn how to use a class.

Comment: Hi. Sorry if i'm hassling you but having difficulties with the concept. To store accounts, which data structure should I use in which class.And which data structure should I use for transaction and which class should it been in?

Comment: Take a step back, and think about the reality. Whare a bank accounts stored? In a bank, isn't it? So Bank should contain BanckAccounts. What do you make transactions with? With an account. So BankAccount should contain transactions. You need to remember the 6 latest transaction for each account, so I already told you that a LinkedList was the appropriate data structure. And a Bank needs to contain all its accounts, and you need to be able to find accounts from the bank, based on the account number, so a Map<Integer, BankAccount> is the appropriate data structure.

Comment: The keys of the map being the account numbers, and the values being the accounts themselves. So that you can do accounts.get(123) and get back the bank account identified by the number 123.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this with an array you have to write additional methods and you should put transactions and summery in **one class** (like @JB Nizet says). The best thing is to use an `List`. Otherwise you have to write all method by your own. The methods should look like:

```
import java.util.*;

private List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
public void addTransaction (Transaction t) {
    if (transactions.size() + 1 > 6)
        transactions.remove(0); // deletes the list element on the first place

    transactions.add(t);
}
```

If you really want use an array, call me and I can help you, but I would suggest that you use an List.

I hope that helps you!

Comment: Yeah, for small stuff like this, you really SHOULD use any `List` like (from List interface) class :)

Comment: The big problem is that an array has an fixed size. That means you have to move every element in the array or you create every time a new array.

Comment: I guess using a List implementation class will help to understand OOP better